# Which one is better O(V+E) or O(E*log(V))

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, breadth-first-search, dijkstra

I am trying to solve a problem on Leetcode
https://leetcode.com/problems/path-with-maximum-probability/description/
My solution involed using simple BFS and it got accepted as well, but when I saw the solutions everyone has done it using Dijkstra Algorithm, so I wonder if time complexity of Dijkshtra is better? or is there any other logic behind using Djikstra for this question.
This was my solution-

```
class Solution {
public:
    double maxProbability(int n, vector<vector<int>>& edges, vector<double>& succProb, int start, int end) {
        vector<pair<int,double>> adj[n];
        for(int i=0;i<edges.size();i++){
            adj[edges[i][0]].push_back({edges[i][1],succProb[i]});
            adj[edges[i][1]].push_back({edges[i][0],succProb[i]});
        }
        queue<int> q;
        q.push(start);
        vector<double> dist(n,0.0);
        dist[start]=1;
        while(!q.empty()){
            auto temp=q.front();
            q.pop();
            for(auto it:adj[temp]){
               
               int node=it.first;
               double prob=it.second;
               double newprob=dist[temp]*prob;
                if(newprob>dist[node]){
                    dist[node]=newprob;
                    q.push(node);
                }
                
            }
        }
        return dist[end];
    }
};
```

Comment: Please click the [tag:dsa] tag you added and read its description. Any reason to add totally irrelevant tags?

Comment: To answer the question in the title, E+V is always smaller than E log(V), except in the very trivial case where the graph has at most one edge. In general you can expect E to be larger than V (in fact, if the graph is connected then E >= V-1 is guaranteed), so E+V is less than 2E, and obviously E log(V) is more than 2E.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution does not perform a simple BFS, in particular it is possible that you push a node in the queue more than once and subsequently process an edge more than once. Thus the complexity of your algorithm is not `O(E)`. In fact I believe it can grow up to `O(V * E)`